# Android Java programming: need help creating an object variable

Tags: java, android, json, api, parsing

I'm trying to make an Android application that access RottenTomatoes.com and loads the API data of upcoming movies.

I can successfully obtain the API data, but when I try to parse the data I run into trouble.

Here's the block of code that isn't working:

```
    public class MovieJSONParser {
    static public class MovieParser{    
        static ArrayList<Movie> parseMovie(String jsonString) throws JSONException {

            ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
            JSONObject moviesJSON = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray moviesArray = moviesJSON.getJSONArray("movies");
            Log.d("app", "in MovieJSONParser");
            for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("app", o.toString());
                Log.d("app", "Created a JSON object to put in Movies");

                                // THIS LINE ISN'T WORKING
                Movie movie = new Movie(o);     

                Log.d("app", "after Movie declaration");
                movies.add(movie);
            }
            Log.d("app", "end of MovieJSONParser");
            return movies;
        } 
    }
}
```

I know the line of code that I labeled as not working isn't working because the log comments are all appearing correctly up until the statement:

```
Movie movie = new Movie(o);
```

This line of code is trivial... a simple class object declaration... I have no idea why it's making the program crash... There is no actual error.  The program runs.

Here is my `Movie.class`:

```
    public class Movie extends Activity {
    String url_posterThumbnail, title, year, mpaa_rating;
    int critics_score;

    public Movie(JSONObject o)  throws JSONException {
        Log.d("app", "in Movie");
        this.title = o.getString("title");
        this.year = o.getString("year");
        this.mpaa_rating = o.getString("mpaa_rating");
        this.critics_score = o.getInt("critics_score");
        this.url_posterThumbnail = o.getString("thumbnail");
    }

    public String returnUrl_posterThumbnail() {
        return url_posterThumbnail;
    }

    public void setUrl_posterThumbnail(String url_posterThumbnail) {
        this.url_posterThumbnail = url_posterThumbnail;
    }

    public String returnTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String returnYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String returnMpaa_rating() {
        return mpaa_rating;
    }

    public void setMpaa_rating(String mpaa_rating) {
        this.mpaa_rating = mpaa_rating;
    }

    public int returnCritics_score() {
        return critics_score;
    }

    public void setCritics_score(int critics_score) {
        this.critics_score = critics_score;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie [url_posterThumbnail=" + url_posterThumbnail + ", title="
                + title + ", year=" + year + ", mpaa_rating=" + mpaa_rating
                + ", critics_score=" + critics_score + "]";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.movies, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's my `MainActivity.class` in case you need it:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String APIKEY = "vs6hcrs57h4wy74u3zgxhmrm";
    String url_MY_FAVORITE_MOVIES = "";
    String url_BOX_OFFICE_MOVIES = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit=3&country=us&apikey=p53b5bybwxpg7nfykwzezkzr";
    String url_IN_THEATRES_MOVIES = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json?page_limit=3&page=1&country=us&apikey=p53b5bybwxpg7nfykwzezkzr";
    String url_OPENING_MOVIES = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/opening.json?limit=3&country=us&apikey=p53b5bybwxpg7nfykwzezkzr";
    String url_UPCOMING_MOVIES = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/upcoming.json?page_limit=3&page=1&country=us&apikey=p53b5bybwxpg7nfykwzezkzr";
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("app", "Hi!  In onCreate");
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.add("My Favorite Movies");
        arrayAdapter.add("Box Office Movies");
        arrayAdapter.add("In Theatres Movies");
        arrayAdapter.add("Opening Movies");
        arrayAdapter.add("Upcoming Movies");

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int listViewPosition,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MoviesDetails.class);

                switch (listViewPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        try {
                            movies = new GetMoviesASYNCTASK(MainActivity.this).execute(url_MY_FAVORITE_MOVIES).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("app", "right before starting MoviesDetails activity");
                        i.putExtra("movies", movies);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        try {
                            movies = new GetMoviesASYNCTASK(MainActivity.this).execute(url_BOX_OFFICE_MOVIES).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("app", "right before starting MoviesDetails activity");
                        i.putExtra("movies", movies);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        try {
                            movies = new GetMoviesASYNCTASK(MainActivity.this).execute(url_IN_THEATRES_MOVIES).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("app", "right before starting MoviesDetails activity");
                        i.putExtra("movies", movies);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        try {
                            movies = new GetMoviesASYNCTASK(MainActivity.this).execute(url_OPENING_MOVIES).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("app", "right before starting MoviesDetails activity");
                        i.putExtra("movies", movies);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        try {
                            movies = new GetMoviesASYNCTASK(MainActivity.this).execute(url_UPCOMING_MOVIES).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d("app", "right before starting MoviesDetails activity");
                        i.putExtra("movies", movies);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;  

                    default: 
                        break;
                }
                Log.d("app", "end of file?");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Lastly, here's my `GetMoviesASYNCTASK.class` if you need it:

```
    public class GetMoviesASYNCTASK extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Movie>> {
    String url_string;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    MainActivity main;

    public GetMoviesASYNCTASK(MainActivity main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {
        url_string = params[0];
//      pd = new ProgressDialog(main);
//      pd.setCancelable(false);
//      pd.setMessage("Loading Movies...!");
//      pd.show();
        Log.d("app", "begin asynctask");

        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_string);//Parse the string as an url  
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //create a http connection using that url
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");//Use the get method
            con.connect();  //Connect to http
            int statusCode = con.getResponseCode();//Get the server's response
            if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  //If server returns 200
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                Log.d("app", "String value of API stored");
                ArrayList<Movie> movies = MovieJSONParser.MovieParser.parseMovie(sb.toString());
                Log.d("app", "movies in ASYNCTASK initialized :)");
                return movies;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Log.d("app", "asynctask didn't work");
        return null;
    }

    // Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> result) {
        //ArrayList<String> movieTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("app", "exiting asynctask");
        //pd.dismiss();
    }


}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just post your logcat trace to let us know what is the error you get

Comment: *Am I missing something obvious? confused* - **DON'T** instantiate activities on your own(as `Movie` extends `Activity` and you're creating a list of them), activities should only be started by the system or through a `startActivity()` call. Also, define *isn't working*.

Comment: Here's the LogCat trace output when I click on "Box Office Movies":

06-19 20:58:11.076: E/Trace(1275): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-19 20:59:04.716: E/Trace(1294): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: @Luksprog 

By "isn't working" I mean the app is supposed to make a Movie object and add it to an ArrayList<Movie> that will be returned to the ASYNCTASK which will then be returned to the MainActivity and will then be added to an intent which will then be sent to a new activity called MoviesDetails.java.

However, when the app gets to the line "Movie movie = new Movie(o);" the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

critics_score is in ratings object but here you are trying to access that key directly. so it is throwing exception.

Better use optString() with some default value instead of getString(), as even if the key doesn't exist, will not end with exceptions..

---

Here is the working code :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray records = object.getJSONArray("movies");

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "records" + records);

int len = records.length();

String albumart[] = new String[len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    JSONObject record = (JSONObject) records.getJSONObject(i);

    String extid = record.getString("id");

    String accountName = record.optString("title", "No title");

    JSONObject posters = record.getJSONObject("posters");

    String albuart = posters.optString("detailed", null);

    String critics = record.optString("critics_consensus", "No Critics");

    String year = record.getString("year");

    String rating = record.optString("mpaa_rating", "No rating");

    JSONObject ratings = record.getJSONObject("ratings");
    String rating = ratings.optString("critics_score", "");

    if(rating.length() <= 0 ) {
        rating = "0";
    }

    String audience_rating = ratings.optString("audience_rating", "");

    if(audience_rating.length() <= 0 ) {
        audience_rating = "0";
    }

    String duration = record.optString("runtime", "");

    if(duration.length() <= 0 ) {
        duration = "0"
    }
}
```